# Automotive connector identification

Tags: connector, identification, automotive

I'd appreciate any help with identifying the connector in the photo below.

It's a button bar connector in a PSA (Peugeot/Citroen) car. Inside the brown shell there is a  2 x 5 2.54 mm pitch socket. The black thing is a lever which turns left on the brown pin when latched (the two extrusions to the right of the pin act like a part of a cog wheel against similar teeth inside the socket).

The imprinted letter seem to describe the type of plastic used, not the connector itself.

[image: Automotive connector]

Comment: PBT stands for Polybutylene terephthalate, a plastic used as an electrical insulator. GF15 means 15 % glass-fibre reinforcement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the make and part number

It's A TYCO/TE/Amphenol FCI connector
Part number is: PBT-GF15

It's not unusual for automotive connectors to be custom to the application.